# jQuery editing multiple elements based a on data-tags HTML5

Tags: jquery, html

I am writing my first jquery snippet and i am trying to build a cool filtering system whereby there are two lists of filters one for developers and one for systems.

```
<div class="filters">
  <ul>
    <li><a data-filter="dev-monkey" href="#">monkey one</a></li>
    <li><a data-filter="dev-monkey2" href="#">monkey two</a></li>
    <li><a data-filter="dev-monkey3" href="#">monkey three</a></li>
    ...
  </ul>
</div>

<div class="filters">
  <ul>
    <li><a data-filter="system-zoo" href="#">the zoo</a></li>
    <li><a data-filter="system-jungle" href="#">the jungle</a></li>
    <li><a data-filter="system-ocean" href="#">the ocean</a></li>
    ...
  </ul>
</div>
```

and so what i would like is when someone is clicked for the filter the name to change color, but you can have multiple filters running at the same time. so someone could see all the systems monkey is working on.

so far i have got it to do this

```
$('.filters a').click(function(){
  $('.filters a').css('color','black');
  $(this).css('color','red');
});
```

so this will highlight the filter you just clicked on red and then make all the others black.

from here i am a deep in it.

so if a link `data-filter='dev-*'` is clicked all devs go black and the clicked dev goes red.
and if a `data-filter='system-*'` is clicked all the systems go black and the selected system stays red with the selected dev.

i thought of

```
 var filter = $(this).attr('data-filter');
 var group = filter.split('-')[0];
 var tag = filter.split('-')[1];
```

splitting the data filter info so i know the group that it belongs in.

but i think i am overthinking it. is there an easy way to iterate for each data type?

Comment: You can use `$(this).data()` to catch your `data-..` attributes.

Comment: `var tag = $(this).data('filter').split('-')[1]`?

Comment: i tried calling `.data()` and its returning the object.

Comment: Yes it is. So you need to pass an argument what data you want, for example `$(this).data('filter')` returns your `data-filter` value.